# When are Property Imports Satisfied?

Tags: c#, mef

When are property imports satisfied?  I thought they would be satisfied before the constructor, as properties are initialized before the constructor runs, but the following example shows `ImportedClass` to be null in the constructor.

I know I can resolve this by using an ImportingConstuctor; this is for sake of understanding when the property imports are satisfied.

```
public MyClass
{
  [Import]
  public ImportedClass ImportedClass {get;set;}

  public MyClass()
  {
      //Imported Class is null at this point, so nothing can be done with it here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An object cannot be manipulated before its constructor is being called. MEF provides a solution for your problem though, with an interface called [IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.ipartimportssatisfiednotification.aspx)

```
public MyClass : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
  [Import]
  public ImportedClass ImportedClass {get;set;}

  public MyClass()
  {
      //Imported Class is null at this point, so nothing can be done with it here.
  }

  public void OnImportsSatisfied() 
  {
     //ImportedClass is set at this point.
  }
}
```

About the actions MEF takes to set your imports; it first calls the constructor, then sets any properties, then calls the notification method.